# Visual Studio Code 2019 not letting me use c++ 17 features

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-code, c++17

I'm very new to C++ and following tutorials and for one of the examples I need to use c++ 17 but when I set the visual studio code to c++17 nothing seems to change, I've restarted the IDE multiple times hoping that that was the problem.

[Project Properties.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WIOe.png)

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

int main()
{
    std::string name = "Test Name";

    std::string_view firstName(name.c_str(), 3);

    return 0;
}
```

which gives the error: `namespace "std" has no member "string_view"`

Comment: `#include <string_view>`

Comment: You should post your code as **text** (formatted as a code block), not as an image.

Comment: On the attached screenshot you are changing settings for `Debug` and `x64` combination only. And at least `x64` is not marked as active platform you compiled to last time. You probably want to select `All configurations` and `All platforms` before changing the language version setting to always apply it.